# Java LinkedList ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator

I wrote a simple code for LinkedList, to add data into it and iterate over it,
I imported the required packages for LinkedList and Iterator,
There is no error in the Code,
**I am getting the following Exception -**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(Unknown Source)
    at collectionFramework.Demo.displayList(LinkedListDemo.java:38)
    at collectionFramework.LinkedListDemo.main(LinkedListDemo.java:13)
```

**Here's my code -**

```
package collectionFramework;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class LinkedListDemo{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Demo obj = new Demo();

        obj.addToList();
        obj.displayList();
    }

}

class Demo{

    LinkedList<String> al;
    Iterator<String> itr;  

    Demo(){
        al = new LinkedList<String>();
        itr = al.iterator();
    }

    void addToList(){
          al.add("Aniruddha");  
          al.add("Hitesh");  
          al.add("Rahul");  
          al.add("Kshitij");  
    }

    void displayList(){

        while(itr.hasNext()){  
               System.out.println(itr.next());  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should get `iterator` in your display method, like:

```
void displayList(){
    itr = al.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){  
           System.out.println(itr.next());  
    }
}
```

For the `LinkedList` has a field `modCount`, this field is used to record the number of times this list has been strucutred modified.

> The number of times this list has been *structurally modified*.
>     Structural modifications are those that change the size of the
>     list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in
>     progress may yield incorrect results.

When you first create the `iterator`, the `modCount` is `0`, for the `ListItr` has recorded the `expectedModCount=modCount=0`, after your modification the **list**. the `modCount` has been updated, for your example is **4**.

when iterator, it will compare the iterator's `expectedModCount` and **List** `modCount`, if not equal, the `ConcurrentModifyExpection` throw.

Comment: Because ... after the creation of the interator in the constructor, addList is called, changing (concurrently) the list, and on the first usage of the iterator in displayList it detects the concurrent change.

Comment: Correct, good catch. The iterator was created too early, then items were added to the collection thereby invalidating the iterator. Exception thrown when you went to use the no-longer-valid iterator.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add or remove an element from the list once you obtain the iterator from the list.
Following code should work.

```
void displayList(){
    Iterator<String> itr = al.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){  
           System.out.println(itr.next());  
    }
}
```

For further reading refer the following link:

[Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re)

http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2014/04/fail-fast-iterator-vs-fail-safe-iterator-difference-with-example-in-java.html

Answer (score 2):

First you get

```
 itr = al.iterator();
```

Then you add some elements to list

```
al.add("Aniruddha");  
al.add("Hitesh");  
al.add("Rahul");  
al.add("Kshitij");
```

Which makes the iterator obsolete.

You should get new iterator before  displaying list

```
void displayList(){
    itr = al.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){  
           System.out.println(itr.next());  
    }
}
```

Or add elements via iterator:

```
itr.add("Aniruddha");  
itr.add("Hitesh");  
...
```

But this is not what you want, as `hasNext()` on `itr` will return false